# how to change the text of button using a variable or return value from function

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget

i want to set the text of button as random alphabet i used set text property of button and passed variable which contains the random alphabet

```
 import java.util.Random;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class OnePlayerEasy extends Activity {
char z;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.oneplayereasy);

}

public void gen(View v) {
    Random r = new Random();

    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        z = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);//button i want               to genrate random no on
        button.setText(z);
    } // prints random characters


}
 }
```

Comment: Return the random char in your function, and than do `yourButton.setText(gen());` (no need for parameter View anymore)

Answer (score 0):

**Here what you can do :**

```
public class OnePlayerEasy extends Activity {
char z;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.oneplayereasy);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setText(gen());

}
   public String gen() {
    Random r = new Random();
    char z = 0;
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        z = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
    } // prints random characters
    return String.valueOf(z);
}
}
```

Comment: not working the application stops . setText not taking generated(gen()) value error is coming as "cannot run the activity"

Comment: I have updated my code please try this now. Just changed Char to String.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to set random character to button title, if i'm right try the following code

```
int min = 0;
int max = 25;
Random r = new Random();
int randomIndex = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setText(alphabet.charAt(randomIndex));
```

if you want to shuffle alphabet and set all characters to button try the next thing

```
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(alphabet.length());
for ( char c : alphabet.toCharArray() ) {
   chars.add(c);
}
Collections.shuffle(chars);
char[] shuffled = new char[chars.size()];
for ( int i = 0; i < shuffled.length; i++ ) {
   shuffled[i] = chars.get(i);
}
String shuffledWord = new String(shuffled);
button.setText(shuffledWord);
```

The second one will give you shuffled alphabet